# Add conditional formating to updated cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I am working on an Excel launch tracker sheet that gets most of its information from an external database. I have code that compares the two sheets to add missing information from the database extract to my launch tracker sheet.

This code is comparing if three conditions match between the two sheets and if so, it replaces the line (from column E until column AQ), if not it adds up the line at the end of the launch tracking sheet.

How do I add conditional formatting to the updated cells?

This is the code I have so far!

```
Option Explicit
Public Const FM As String = "Launch Tracker"
Public Const lidebFM As Byte = 3
Public Const FL As String = "LAT - Master Data"
Public Const lidebFL As Byte = 3
Public Const co1 As Byte = 8  ' colonne H
Public Const co2 As Byte = 15 ' colonne O
Public Const co3 As Byte = 17 ' colonne Q
Public Sub Update()
Dim lifinFL As Long, liFL As Long
Dim lifinFM As Long, liFM As Long
Dim obj As Object
Dim V1 As String, V2 As String, V3 As String
With Sheets(FL)
  ' dernière ligne feuille FL
  lifinFL = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
  ' boucle sur les lignes de FL
  For liFL = lidebFL To lifinFL
    ' dernière ligne de FM
    lifinFM = Sheets(FM).Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ' comparaison des Item ID
    V1 = .Cells(liFL, co1).Value
    ' recherche de V1 dans FM colonne co1
    Set obj = Sheets(FM).Columns(co1).Find(V1, , , xlWhole)
    ' si pas trouve lifm = 1° ligne dispo dans FM pour copie
    If obj Is Nothing Then
      liFM = lifinFM + 1
    ' sinon V1 est trouve à la ligne liFM
    Else
      liFM = obj.Row
      ' compraison de MARKET et SAP
      V2 = .Cells(liFL, co2).Value
      V3 = .Cells(liFL, co3).Value
      ' si identiques on garde liFM = liobj pour ecrasement
      If V2 = Sheets(FM).Cells(liFM, co2).Value And V3 = Sheets(FM).Cells(liFM, co3).Value Then
        ' rien
      Else
      ' si non identiques lifm = 1° ligne dispo dans FM pour copie
        liFM = lifinFM + 1
      End If
    End If
    ' copie de la ligne liFL dans FM à la ligne liFM
    '.Rows(liFL).Copy Sheets(FM).Cells(liFM, 1)
    'prendre juste les cellules à la place de la ligne
    .Range(.Cells(liFL, 5), .Cells(liFL, 43)).Copy Sheets(FM).Cells(liFM, 5)
  Next liFL
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be best to show what you've done first. You can add formatting of a cell quite easily as part of your update process.

Comment: Just realized I messed up the code formatting, but there it is... But since I am copying a gorup of cells how can I differencitate those who have been updated and those who haven't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If painting the updated line in a different color suits you, you can use something as simple as this (makes the line yellow):

```
Range("E" & currLine & ":AQ" & currLine).Interior.Color = 65535
```

Of course before launching the loop which updates data you should paint the whole sheet into one color (white or any other).

Comment: Yes but the problem is that there is a lot of changes that could be made on the line, and I would like to know if it is possible to put different formatting only on cells which value have changed

Comment: Then instead of a line-range you can use a single cell, changing it's formatting right after you change it's value (and still have the indexes in hand).

Comment: But I don't understand how to implement that as I am already changing the line, it would mean I would have to rewrite entirely the code to use single cells instead..?